# Deducing parameters from initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

So here is the scenario I have been to trying to work upon

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <complex>

class Double
{
  private:
  double dd;
  std::vector<double> gg;

  std::string ss;

  public:
     Double(double d,const std::string& s = std::string())
     {
         dd = d;
         ss = s;
         gg = std::vector<double>();
     }

     Double(const std::vector<double>& d,const std::string& s = std::string())
     {
         dd = 0;
         ss = s;
         gg = d;
     }

     double getdd() const { return dd; }
};

template<typename T>
Double getDouble(T t,const std::string& s = std::string())
{
    return Double(t,s);
}

std::string to_string(Double d)
{
     double zd = d.getdd() + 1.0;
    return std::to_string(zd);
}

 class TEST 
 {
    public:
    template<typename T_0>
    TEST(const T_0 & var_0)
    {
        auto x = to_string(getDouble(var_0));
    }
};


int main()
{
    TEST ds ({3.4,"ssd"});

    std::cout << "Reached heare\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Essentially if I call

`Double dd ({3.4,"ssd"});`

everything works fine but if I try the same thing with the class `TEST`, I get the following error.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:57:25: error: no matching function for call to 'TEST::TEST(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
     TEST ds ({3.4,"ssd"});
                         ^
main.cpp:48:5: note: candidate: template<class T_0> TEST::TEST(const T_0&)
     TEST(const T_0 & var_0)
     ^
main.cpp:48:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:57:25: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T_0'
     TEST ds ({3.4,"ssd"});
                         ^
main.cpp:44:8: note: candidate: constexpr TEST::TEST(const TEST&)
  class TEST 
        ^
main.cpp:44:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const TEST&'
main.cpp:44:8: note: candidate: constexpr TEST::TEST(TEST&&)
main.cpp:44:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'TEST&&'
```

I have tried to deduce the parameters adding a constructor as below

`Double (std::initializer_list<boost::any> xx)`

but it hasnt worked for me.

Is there any way to get past this issue ? I cant use the explicit type at the callsite since the elements of the initializer list are not of the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the braced-init-list doesn't have any type; the template parameter `T_0` can't be [deduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) from it.

You can use [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead.

```
template<typename... T_0>
TEST(const T_0 & ... var_0)
{
    auto x = to_string(getDouble(var_0...));
}
```

then use it like

```
TEST ds (3.4,"ssd");
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1n8AiJcxGAvalFOd)

Answer (score 0):

This call works

```
Double dd ({3.4,"ssd"});
```

because there is appropriate constructor

```
 Double(double d,const std::string& s = std::string())
 {
     dd = d;
     ss = s;
     gg = std::vector<double>();
 }
```

This call

```
TEST ds ({3.4,"ssd"});
```

does not work because the template constructor has only one parameter

```
    template<typename T_0>
    TEST(const T_0 & var_0)
    {
        auto x = to_string(getDouble(var_0));
    }
```

Pay attention to that this construction `{3.4,"ssd"}` does not have a type. SO the compiler reports that

```
main.cpp:48:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:57:25: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T_0'
     TEST ds ({3.4,"ssd"});
                         ^
```

Comment: @songyuanyao It could if you have a compound type for example a structure and a corresponding constructor parameter of which has the structure type.

Comment: @songyuanyao How the constructor parameters are declared.